# SCNCamera movement synchronized to iPhone accelerometer

Tags: scenekit

I am working on an iOS/Swift project which contains a scene (SceneKit).
What I want to do is to rotate `SCNCamera` when the user rotates their phone.

Here's what I've done:

```
    motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1

    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] (data: CMAccelerometerData?, error: Error?) in self?.update_rotation(p: (data?.acceleration)!) }
```

and in the `update_rotation` function:

```
   camera_node.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(angle_x,angle_y,angle_z)
```

`camera_node` is my `SCNNode` camera object. `angle_x` and `angle_z` are calculated from the accelerometers data. (I just multiply the accelerometer value by 90 and I convert it into radians). `angle_y` is calculated from the compass (north angle).

My problem comes from `angle_z`. It is very strange because the behavior of `eulerAngles.z` property depends on the `angle_y` value.
In other words, everything works great if a look to the north direction.
When I am looking to the South, `angle_z` needs to be inverted.
I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0
if motionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main, withHandler: { (devMotion, error) -> Void in
        cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(
            -Float((devMotion?.attitude.roll)!) - Float(M_PI_2),
            Float((motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude.yaw)!),
            -Float((motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude.pitch)!)
        )
    })}
```

I try this with my playground app in iPad

Comment: There exactly the same problem. I removed the two minus in your SCNVector3 because i am working in Landscape - home left. If i tilt my phone left/right, this is not working when i am looking behind